# How do I get a list of all installed Applications In Java?

Tags: java, android

In My example i have only Apps - which installed himself and not show default installed apps in system.

How correcting example for get all Apps(with default installed) but without System Process ???

```
public ArrayList<String> InstalledApps(String vector)
{
    ArrayList<String> appsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<PackageInfo> PackList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i=0; i < PackList.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo PackInfo = PackList.get(i);
        if ( ( (PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true)
        {
            String AppName = PackInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            appsList.add(vector+"::"+PackInfo.packageName+"::"+AppName);
        }
    }
    return appsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help people !!!

I himself found a method:

```
public ArrayList<String> InstalledApps(String vector)
{
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    ArrayList<String> appsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> PackList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : PackList) {

        String AppName = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        String PackName = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if(appsList.contains(PackName)){ continue; }
        appsList.add(vector+"::"+PackName+"::"+AppName);
        }return appsList;
    }
```